# Simple php mysql query returns only one of two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a PHP and MySQL newbie trying to write a simple query against a table consisting of 2 columns: one with a text string and the second with a date string.  The code below returns the first column (the text string) but not the second date string:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('archive')or die("cannot select db");
$string = $_POST['keywords'];
$search_query = "SELECT text, date_written FROM archive_table WHERE text LIKE '%$string%'";
$result = mysql_query($search_query,$link);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 0) {
    echo "sorry, I haven&#8217;t written about ".$string." yet.";
    }
    $count = 0;
    while ($count < $rows) {
        echo mysql_result($result, $count);
        echo "\n\n";
        $count = $count + 1;
    }

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

I've tried the following code to replace "echo mysql_result($result, $count);", but it returns nothing at all:

```
echo mysql_result($result['text'], $result['date_written'], $count);
```

I'm hoping it's a fairly simple syntax blunder that is easily fixed.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use the `mysql_*` functions, as they're deprecated and not safe.  Use either MySQLi or PDO
2. You also need to fetch your results:

   ```
   $query = "blah"
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo "{$row['text']}, {$row['date_written]}";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this

```
echo mysql_result($result['haiku_text'], $result['date_written'], $count);
```

should be

```
echo mysql_result($result['text'], $result['date_written'], $count);
```

You have a prefix in front of the text field but it doesn't have one when you select it.

Comment: "haiku_text" was a typo.  I've fixed it in my example above.